# Why do I have grub file in my home directory?

Tags: grub2, home-directory

Somehow, there's `/home/zlatan/grub` file, owned by root and read-only for basic user.

Its content is exactly this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

`/etc/default/grub` is completely same as `/home/zlatan/grub`. Its filetype is ASCII text.

I want to know is it safe to remove such file.

Comment: You probably accidentally copied it from `/etc/default`.

Comment: just to be sure we give you the right advice, [edit] with the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` and `file /etc/default/grub`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to remove this file from your user directory.

There is no value to keep it there, unless as a backup copy.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. It really has no use — I deleted it and grub booted normally.